# JK flip flop not toggling when both inputs are 1?

Tags: simulation, flipflop

[image]

Instead of toggling, this circuit throws this error. What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: It is level-triggered. So your clock period is probably too long so it is changing the state several times during one period.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I changed the clock's frequency to the maximum available value and I still get this error

Comment: I am not sure how this thing is simulating. Do the gates have propagation delay simulated? Also it is indeed expected to oscillate. So maybe just follow the advise and single-step it?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I looked it up and on the github page it said to run it in single step mode to figure out the case of oscillations and so I did, and it toggled normally like it should.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't get the error right away when I set the J and K inputs to 1 at the start, I only get the error when the first toggle is supposed to happen

Comment: you are using incorrect logic gates

Comment: @jsotola I don't see how...?

Comment: try using 3 input AND gates

Comment: @jsotola Tried, same issue.

Comment: Are JK floating?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 What does that mean?

Comment: Floating for CMOS means not terminated.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 No idea. I sent an email to my professor about this, he said that this happens, to just run it step by step. Meanwhile the simulator has built in flip flops. No issue with those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try this instead](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.634267539816555+50+5+50%0A151+432+144+528+144+0+2+5+5%0A151+432+256+528+256+0+2+0+5%0Aw+432+224+432+240+0%0Aw+432+160+432+176+0%0Aw+528+224+528+256+0%0Aw+528+224+432+176+0%0Aw+528+144+528+176+0%0Aw+528+176+432+224+0%0A151+320+128+432+128+0+2+0+5%0A151+320+272+432+272+0+2+5+5%0Aw+320+144+320+256+0%0Aw+320+256+320+336+0%0A151+192+144+288+144+0+2+5+5%0A151+192+256+288+256+0+2+0+5%0Aw+320+112+288+112+0%0Aw+288+112+288+144+0%0Aw+288+256+288+288+0%0Aw+288+288+320+288+0%0Aw+192+160+192+176+0%0Aw+192+240+192+224+0%0Aw+288+224+288+256+0%0Aw+288+224+192+176+0%0Aw+288+176+288+144+0%0Aw+288+176+192+224+0%0A151+80+128+192+128+0+3+5+5%0AI+64+336+320+336+0+0.5+5%0AM+528+144+592+144+0+2.5%0AM+528+256+592+256+0+2.5%0Ax+518+117+536+120+4+24+Q%0Ax+520+305+538+308+6+24+Q%0Aw+32+112+80+112+0%0Ax+31+99+43+102+4+24+J%0AR+64+336+32+336+1+2+120+2.5+2.5+0+0.5%0A151+80+272+192+272+0+3+5+5%0Aw+432+160+432+64+0%0Aw+432+64+80+64+0%0Aw+80+64+80+128+0%0AL+32+288+-96+288+0+1+false+5+0%0Ax+22+272+38+275+4+24+K%0Aw+64+336+64+256+0%0Aw+64+256+80+256+0%0Aw+80+144+64+144+0%0Aw+64+144+64+256+0%0Aw+32+288+80+288+0%0Aw+432+240+432+368+0%0Aw+432+368+80+368+0%0Aw+80+368+80+272+0%0AL+32+112+-96+112+0+1+false+5+0%0Ax+-148+128+-88+131+4+14+click%5Cshere%0Ao+47+64+0+4102+5+0.00009765625+0+2+47+3+J%0Ao+37+64+0+4102+5+0.00009765625+0+2+37+3+K%0Ao+26+64+0+4102+5+0.00009765625+0+1+Q%0Ao+32+64+0+4102+5+0.00009765625+0+2+32+3+clk%0A)

Notice there are 2 stages of latches to make the clock edge sensitive.
 [image]

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look